How to insert LaTeX commands and matching braces repeatedly?
I sometimes have to insert again and again commands such as:
\onslide<->{ SOME TEXT }

when I create beamer presentations and I wonder if the vim-surround plugin could facilitate (a lot!) the process.
What I would like to do would be to select in visual mode some text and have a command that not only surround the selected text with "{" - which is already easily done with vim-surround - but would also insert "\onslide<->" before it.
Does anyone know how to do such a thing? If it is possible at all... or would there be another more efficient plugin for that?

You don't need a plugin at all, Vim can do this out of the box.
You can visual-select some text and then do
s\onslide<->{<C-R>"}<Esc>

The s will remove the visual selection and enter insert mode. Then type "\onslide<->{" and paste the selection you just removed with Ctrl-R". Append the closing brace and press Esc to return to normal mode.
The obvious caveat is that this will clobber the unnamed register. You can specify any register to use that one, instead.
See :help s and :help i_CTRL-R for reference.
The other option is to use the :substitute command like this:
:s/\%V.*\%V/\\onslide<->{&}/

The \%Vs will constrain the match to the visual area.* matches everything. In the replacement string, & will insert the matched text.
Related help topics are :help :substitute, :help /\%V and :help s/\&.
If you need this command repeatedly, it's probably a good idea to create a mapping, either in your vimrc or (better) in .vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim. It may be sensible to also create a normal mode mapping that works on the current word - no need for visual selection:
:xnoremap <buffer> <your key> s\onslide<->{<C-R>"}<Esc>
:nnoremap <buffer> <your key> caw\onslide<->{<C-R>"}<Esc>

Where <your key> is replaced with the key (sequence) you want to assign the mapping to. I'd suggest something along the lines of <Leader>o or an F-key.
More information can be found in :help mapping, :help mapmode-x and :help map-<buffer>.

OK, thanks a ton, it works perfectly out of the box !! Life/hours saving trick...

Glad it helped. Regular visitors to this site will know that I'm just unable to memorize vim-surround's key mappings :-)

They'll know you don't need it for that particular application ;-)... and your answer is amazingly detailed, BTW, so thanks for that too : I did learn a lot on what kind of things can be done :-)

I have an odd behaviour : when I select several lines, it does insert the command as I wish but it goes with an extra set of spaces that increases at each line... does this sound like normal behaviour ? Is it due to some autoindentation that would interfere with the process ?

@user22744 I never tested with multiple lines but the operation is straightforward enough. I will look into it. I think I've seen the case where TeX indentation gets thrown off. You can search for existing questions and see if any of them fixes your issue.

@user22744 I can't reproduce any indentation hiccups. I do remember having seen such problems in TeX, especially when a backslash was inserted. If existing answers don't work for you, consider asking a new question.

OK, thank you so so much ! I haven't figured out a solution yet : I'll probably ask a new question, then.

Try :help surround-customizing, which suggests that the following will make yssS surround the line with \onslide<->{}:
let b:surround_{char2nr('S')} = "\\onslide<->{\r}"

You could drop that in a tex ftplugin, if you wanted.
(I've not provided space around the replaced content because TeX and LaTeX are picky about spaces in code.)
For LaTeX code that works as \begin{foo}…\end{foo}, you can also use the l or \ replacements (undocumented, if I recall), so for example yss\foo<enter>.

Thanks a lot for your answer !!

There is a plugin sandwich.vim that provides out-of-the-box support for tex files. In particular, what you described can be done with visually highlighting the text, followed by
saconslide<->

where sa stands for "sandwich add", and
c stands for a tex command.

Thanks a lot for that suggestion ! I'm definitely going to have a look at sandwich :-) Although, here, it seems thatyou have to type in the command each time ? Or is it possible to bind a key for that whole command, with the same philosophy that Friedrich's solution ? Which works fine, BTW, outside of multiline situations, so far.

@user22744 the operation is dot-repeatable, so you could move to the next line and simply press . (without additional plugins!)

Thanks ! Is it dot repeatable on a visual selection ? Because I do use it on visual selections, mostly. Well, at this point I could try but I am not preparing a beamer right now... So lazy !
